# Why Android uiautomator's UiDevice#takeScreenshot always return false on emulator

Tags: android

When using **uiautomator**, `takeScreenshot(File storePath)` always returns false no matter what parameter I pass in.

I've tried to give either `new File(dir_name, file_name)` or  `new File(file_name)`, neither of them works (of course mkdir first if the dir_name doesn't exist).

Every time it just return false and ***/data/local/tmp/*** on emulator is empty.

BTW, I don't think it's a permission problem, since trying the similar `dumpWindowHierarchy` could generate a dump file there.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: how to add uiautomator to our project, i need to take screen shot please help me...

Comment: @kalandar please follow steps on this link: http://developer.android.com/tools/testing/testing_ui.html  it's detailed enough.  Basically for setting up the project, you need to add JUnit3 lib support and uiautomator.jar + android.jar.

Comment: thank you @Jing li.... i will do it

Comment: yes i implemented in my project but i can't able to create object fo UiDevice... please give me some code sample...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you are using emulator to run the tests you should **turn on "Use Host GPU" in your AVD configuration**. After this change it worked for me.

If you still got a problem you may try screencap. It is command line tool for taking screenshots. It works in both emulator settings. To save screenshot in given *path* execute:

```
Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("screencap <path>");
process.waitFor();
```

Use **/data/local/tmp** to avoid problems with permission. You can use SD Card dir as well. It is asynchronous so wait until process is finished with waitFor(). It will recognize desired output format by extension of provided file.

Or you can get PNG in InputStream (no need to wait):

```
Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("screencap -p");
InputStream output = new BufferedInputStream(process.getInputStream());
```

You can omit -p if you wish to get file in JPEG. They JPEG screenshots are bigger, but it takes less time to get them.

Comment: thanks for your answer, it solves my problem after enabling "Use Host GPU".  Yes, the screenshot function usually built based on the rendering approach.  And my opinion is, as if the built in function works, we should not use external lib to do the same thing.

Comment: Is there a way to do it using android's UiDevice takeScreeshot method ? I am trying this on device but there also it fails and gives result as false always. The directory gets created but it remains empty after the call to takeScreeshot method.

Answer (score 3):

The takeScreenshot() method is applicable from 4.2 and above android version devices

If the device version is appropriate, then use the following piece of code

```
File path = new File("/sdcard/filename.png");
    int SDK_VERSION = android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT; 
    if (SDK_VERSION >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN_MR1) {
        mUiAutomatorTestCase.getUiDevice().takeScreenshot(PATH);
    }
```

We can view the file by following command

```
$ adb shell ls -l /sdcard/name-of-file
```